# PHP - erro Std::Class

Tags: php, request

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
case 'operator-autentication':
    global $decoded;
    $array = array();
    $user = $decoded->user;
    $pass = $decoded->pass;
    $opr = new opr_func();
    $arrResp = $opr->loginFunc($user, $pass);
    if(empty($arrResp) == true) {
        $array[] = array('id' => '0');
    } else {
        foreach($opr->loginOperator($decoded->code, $decoded->pass) as $ip) {
            $array[] = array('id' => $ip->id, 'name' => $ip->name, 'clientId' => $ip->clientId);
        }
    }        
    echo json_encode($array);
    break;
```

Quando testo um envio de parâmetros ele acontece o erro:

> ↵**Notice**: Undefined property: stdClass::$user in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bullGreenPanel/assets/php/client/AppCollect.php** on line **94**

Caso não use a var `$decoded->code` (que é a que vem no aplicativo) funciona, qual seria motivo e solução ?

Ps: 
no inicio do código tem :

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$decoded = json_decode($postdata);
```

Comment: Depois de global $decoded coloque um print_r desta variável. Veja o conteúdo da mesma e poste para que possamos entender o que ela contém.

Comment: Aparentemente `$decoded` não possui o atributo `user`.

Comment: Realmente, falha minha, n possui o atributo user... pfvr coloque uma resposta para dar como ok